# Windows Azure Service Bus Notification Hub Only Receiving Portion of Notifications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, apple-push-notifications, async-await, azure-notificationhub

I have an ASP.NET MVC Controller method similar to below:

```
    public JsonResult GenerateNotifications()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyService.GenerateNotifications());
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My Service method looks like the following:

```
    public async void GenerateNotifications()
    {
        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(AppHelper.AzureNotificationHubConnectionString, "myhub");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var notification = new
            {
                aps = new
                {
                    alert = string.Format("Awesome Notification {0}", i),
                    sound = "default"
                }
            };

            string notificationJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
            NotificationOutcome result = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(notificationJSON, "mytag");
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that out of the 10 notifications i should be receiving, I usually only receiving 5-6 of them.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm handling the `async` calls?

Should I be generating the notifications a different way from the controller?

Comment: Have you tried to introduce a delay and see if you receive all the notifications? It might be that they are getting throttled

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting some exceptions which are getting swallowed because your`GenerateNotification` method is `async void`. You should return a `Task` and make sure that you `await` the method so that the exceptions are observed and rethrown.

Once you have that, instead of using `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyService.GenerateNotifications())` you can just `await MyService.GenerateNotifications()`. See [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for some of the caveats with using `async/await`

I would change your code to this:

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GenerateNotifications()
    {
        await MyService.GenerateNotifications();
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public async Task GenerateNotifications()
    {
        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(AppHelper.AzureNotificationHubConnectionString, "myhub");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var notification = new
            {
                aps = new
                {
                    alert = string.Format("Awesome Notification {0}", i),
                    sound = "default"
                }
            };

            string notificationJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
            NotificationOutcome result = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(notificationJSON, "mytag");
        }
    }
```

At the moment you are also sending out your notifications serially. You can send them out in parallel by adding the resulting tasks to a list and then using `await Task.WhenAll` to `await` their completion.

```
public async Task GenerateNotifications()
{
    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(AppHelper.AzureNotificationHubConnectionString, "myhub");

    List<Task<NotificationOutcome>> notificaitonTasks = new List<Task<NotificationOutcome>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var notification = new
        {
            aps = new
            {
                alert = string.Format("Awesome Notification {0}", i),
                sound = "default"
            }
        };

        string notificationJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification);
        notificaitonTasks.Add(hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(notificationJSON, "mytag"));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(notificaitonTasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I've implemented these (including Task.WhenAll) and it still appears to not send all notifications (ex. only 4 of 6). Any other thoughts?

Comment: is it the same clients that always receive the notifications or is it behaving randomly?